# Remove rows that contain different letters or missing data for two columns

Tags: r, mapping, bioinformatics, blast

I'm analyzing a big dataset in R studio and I am not very experienced in programming.
I would want to remove the rows that contain different letters for columns CONSENSUSMAP and SVEVOMAP. Also, if missing data for column "CONSENSUSMAP".

I write this table as an example:

```
CLONEID | CONSENSUSMAP| SVEVOMAP
1228104 |      NA     |    chr1A
2277691 |      NA     |    chr1A
2277607 |      1A     |    chr1A
1E+08   |      NA     |    chr1A
1229677 |      1B     |    chr1A
1126457 |      7B     |    chr7B
```

I would like to obtain the following output:

```
CLONEID | CONSENSUSMAP| SVEVOMAP
2277607 |       1A    |    chr1A
1126457 |       7B    |    chr7B
```

I tried some codes but none of them fits these specific conditions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `dplyr` solution will do what the question asks for.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  filter(!is.na(CONSENSUSMAP)) %>%
  mutate(newcol = sub("^[^[:digit:]]*(\\d+.*$)", "\\1", SVEVOMAP)) %>%
  filter(CONSENSUSMAP == newcol) %>%
  select(-newcol)
#  CLONEID CONSENSUSMAP SVEVOMAP
#1 2277607           1A    chr1A
#2 1126457           7B    chr7B
```

**Edit.**

Here are two other ways, both with `dplyr`, the second one uses package `stringr`.

```
df1 %>%
  filter(!is.na(CONSENSUSMAP)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(grepl(CONSENSUSMAP, SVEVOMAP))
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#Groups: <by row>
#
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#  CLONEID CONSENSUSMAP SVEVOMAP
#  <chr>   <chr>        <chr>   
#1 2277607 1A           chr1A   
#2 1126457 7B           chr7B   


df1 %>%
  filter(!is.na(CONSENSUSMAP)) %>%
  filter(stringr::str_detect(SVEVOMAP, CONSENSUSMAP))
#  CLONEID CONSENSUSMAP SVEVOMAP
#1 2277607           1A    chr1A
#2 1126457           7B    chr7B
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(CLONEID = c("1228104", "2277691", "2277607", "1e+08", 
"1229677", "1126457"), CONSENSUSMAP = c(NA, NA, "1A", NA, "1B", 
"7B"), SVEVOMAP = c("chr1A", "chr1A", "chr1A", "chr1A", "chr1A", 
"chr7B")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can wrap with `na.omit` and then `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
        filter(!is.na(CONSENSUSMAP)) %>%
        distinct(SVEVOMAP, .keep_all = TRUE)
#  CLONEID CONSENSUSMAP SVEVOMAP
#1 2277607           1A    chr1A
#2 1126457           7B    chr7B
```

Or if it is based on the substring, then

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   filter(!is.na(CONSENSUSMAP), CONSENSUSMAP == str_sub(SVEVOMAP, 4, 5))
#   CLONEID CONSENSUSMAP SVEVOMAP
#1 2277607           1A    chr1A
#2 1126457           7B    chr7B
```

Or with `str_remove`

```
df1 %>%
   filter(!is.na(CONSENSUSMAP), CONSENSUSMAP == str_remove(SVEVOMAP, 'chr'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(CLONEID = c("1228104", "2277691", "2277607", "1e+08", 
"1229677", "1126457"), CONSENSUSMAP = c(NA, NA, "1A", NA, "1B", 
"7B"), SVEVOMAP = c("chr1A", "chr1A", "chr1A", "chr1A", "chr1A", 
"chr7B")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible `base` way:

```
idx <- with(df, !is.na(CONSENSUSMAP) & mapply(grepl, CONSENSUSMAP, SVEVOMAP))

df[idx, ]
```

Output:

```
  CLONEID CONSENSUSMAP SVEVOMAP
3 2277607           1A    chr1A
6 1126457           7B    chr7B
```

Note that this only looks if the whole pattern in `CONSENSUSMAP` matches anything in `SVEVOMAP`.

If you're really only into letters at the end, then let's change the example a bit:

```
  CLONEID CONSENSUSMAP SVEVOMAP
1 1228104         <NA>    chr1A
2 2277691         <NA>    chr1A
3 2277607           1A    chr1A
4   1e+08         <NA>    chr1A
5 1229677           1B    chr1A
6 1126457           7B    chr6B
```

Here, the last record wouldn't be extracted with the previous method, but would be with the next one:

```
idx <- with(df, !is.na(CONSENSUSMAP) & sub('\\d+', '', CONSENSUSMAP) == sub('chr\\d+(.*$)', '\\1', SVEVOMAP))

df[idx, ]

  CLONEID CONSENSUSMAP SVEVOMAP
3 2277607           1A    chr1A
6 1126457           7B    chr6B
```

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable contributions. My problem was solved :)